# numpy eigen decomposition produce unexpected output?

Tags: numpy, algebra, eigenvector

According to documentation of `numpy.linalg.eig` and what I understand about eigen decomposition, the following code :

```
a = [[1,1],[-1,-1]]
w, v = np.linalg.eig(a)
c = a@v
print(c)
print(w)
```

should produce :

```
[[√2,0],[-√2,0]]
[4,0]
```

but instead it produced :

```
[[ 1.11022302e-16+1.11022302e-16j  1.11022302e-16-1.11022302e-16j]
 [-1.11022302e-16-1.11022302e-16j -1.11022302e-16+1.11022302e-16j]]
[-3.25176795e-17+1.57009246e-16j -3.25176795e-17-1.57009246e-16j]
```

so where was I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With matrix `a`

```
a = np.array([[ 1,  1],\
              [-1, -1]])
```

your two eigenvalues should theoretically be `w_th=[0,0]`, so :

```
w
>>> array([-3.25176795e-17+1.57009246e-16j, -3.25176795e-17-1.57009246e-16j])
```

is just some zero +/- round-off error in complex form. Concerning the eigenvectors, these are `v_th=[[1,1],[-1,-1]]` but [numpy.linalg.eig](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.eig.html) normalized them to be unitary length (*e.g.* for the first one `np.linalg.norm(v[:,0],2) = 0.99...`), which means it just gave you an approximation of `[[1/sqrt(2),1/sqrt(2)],[-1/sqrt(2),-1/sqrt(2)]]` :

```
v
>>> array([[ 0.70710678+0.00000000e+00j,  0.70710678-0.00000000e+00j],
            [-0.70710678+1.11022302e-16j, -0.70710678-1.11022302e-16j]])
```

Knowing all of the above, you can now verify it numerically by comparing both sides of the equation [image: formula]:

```
np.allclose(a@v,w*v)
>>> True
```

or with theorical values, *i.e.* "without" round-off errors :

```
a@np.asarray(v_th)
>>> array([[0, 0],
           [0, 0]])

np.asarray(w_th)*np.asarray(v_th)
>>> array([[0, 0],
           [0, 0]])
```

so there is nothing unexpected from numpy output here, seems just that your analytical eigenvalues `[4,0]` are false.